HTTP server is not responding From Outside although firewall is inactive
I have a VPS which has Ubuntu 20.04. When I request the server from inside(when I have active shell) using http -vv GET http://216.10.242.221 it gives proper response. But when I request from outside (i.e. from my laptop's shell) by using that same command then I gets timed out. I am using gunicorn local server as my http server behing nginx proxy server.
In both cases where ufw firewall is active or inactive, I always timed out. When I do sudo tcpdump -i eth0 port 80 and then request from outside, I can see the arriving packets. 
I can login to my server via ssh and I can also ping my server from outside. At this point, I just don't know where to look for and what to look for. All I can do is provide configurations and outputs of some copy pasted commands.

netstat -an --inet | grep LISTEN

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  


sudo ufw status verbose (when ufw is active)

Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
8000                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
8000/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
8090/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
8090                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
8000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
8090/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
8090 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)  


sudo iptables -L -n -v (When iptables is activated through systemctl)

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  726 96078 f2b-sshd   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
  822  112K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   48  2880 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
   44  3930 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 172 packets, 24588 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   14  1112 REJECT     all  --  *      *       42.192.72.115        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   12   956 REJECT     all  --  *      *       216.172.190.206      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   22  1736 REJECT     all  --  *      *       202.129.211.254      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   22  1736 REJECT     all  --  *      *       103.171.84.191       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
  656 90538 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  


I did sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT when I was checking other questions like this.

sudo cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf


user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    # include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    
    

      server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 216.10.242.221;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
    
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}


sudo tcpdump -i eth0 port 80 (after this I go to my laptop's shell and started reqesting)

tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
03:52:13.102238 IP 27.61.248.214.60162 > 216-10-242-221.webhostbox.net.http: Flags [S], seq 1825961432, win 32120, options [mss 1300,sackOK,TS val 649148418 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
03:52:14.121321 IP 27.61.248.214.60162 > 216-10-242-221.webhostbox.net.http: Flags [S], seq 1825961432, win 32120, options [mss 1300,sackOK,TS val 649149433 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
03:52:15.081118 IP 27.61.248.214.60162 > 216-10-242-221.webhostbox.net.http: Flags [S], seq 1825961432, win 32120, options [mss 1300,sackOK,TS val 649150457 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
03:52:16.171276 IP 27.61.248.214.60162 > 216-10-242-221.webhostbox.net.http: Flags [S], seq 1825961432, win 32120, options [mss 1300,sackOK,TS val 649151481 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
03:52:17.181280 IP 27.61.248.214.60162 > 216-10-242-221.webhostbox.net.http: Flags [S], seq 1825961432, win 32120, options [mss 1300,sackOK,TS val 649152505 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
03:52:18.161107 IP 27.61.248.214.60162 > 216-10-242-221.webhostbox.net.http: Flags [S], seq 1825961432, win 32120, options [mss 1300,sackOK,TS val 649153529 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
03:52:20.231282 IP 27.61.248.214.60162 > 216-10-242-221.webhostbox.net.http: Flags [S], seq 1825961432, win 32120, options [mss 1300,sackOK,TS val 649155577 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
03:52:24.281444 IP 27.61.248.214.60162 > 216-10-242-221.webhostbox.net.http: Flags [S], seq 1825961432, win 32120, options [mss 1300,sackOK,TS val 649159609 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
03:52:32.351782 IP 27.61.248.214.60162 > 216-10-242-221.webhostbox.net.http: Flags [S], seq 1825961432, win 32120, options [mss 1300,sackOK,TS val 649167673 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
^C
10 packets captured
10 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel


Here are screenshots of http server running properly inside the VPS but no response outside the VPS: 
http server running properly inside VPS 
timed out when connecting to http server outside VPS

So, the Questions are:

Why my server is not responding to outside http requests?
Why it does not matter that my firewall is active or inactive?
What should be the next step to debug the network packets after watching them arrived?
What do sys-admins do to debug this kind of stuff in general situations?
What are my options if there is no solution to my problem?

Thanks for reading the question.
